# Can't dialogue box to run

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to get a `JOptionPane` dialog box to display but get beachball of death each time I try and run the program.

Code is below:

```
Button submitButton = new Button();

submitButton.setText ("Submit");        
submitButton.setOnAction (e -> {                        
    system001.displaySystemProperties();

    system001.setMake(makeField.getText());
    system001.setModel(modelField.getText());
    system001.setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(speedField.getText()));
    system001.setMemorySize(Integer.parseInt(memoryField.getText()));
    system001.setHardDisk(Double.parseDouble(hdField.getText()));
    system001.setPurchaseCost(Double.parseDouble(costField.getText()));

    system001.displayDetails();
    system001.diagnoseSystem();

    stage.close();

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I want to expand the dialogue box to include text captured from an input GUI but can't even get it to run to say "Hello"

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) **Don't** mix Swing & AWT components. The `Button` should be a `JButton`.

Comment: 5) *"but get beachball of death"* .. What is that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the beach ball is basically the loading icon on macOS. "Of death" = never stopping

Comment: thanks all - @AndrewThompson  for the (new to this as you can tell:) - thanks for the tip on swing/awt - that has solved it